# Write multiple SD cards in parallel, or serially as efficiently as possible

Tags: usb, sd-card, kindle

A friend has handheld devices (Kindles) that we want to transfer a large bundle of files to (videos for a youth project). The devices have SD card readers and so we want to write SD cards with a disk image, or by another fast and efficient method.

Is it possible to, for example, get a USB adaptor with multiple ports, put each SD card in a USB converter, then simply write - eg with `dd` under Ubuntu - to say 8 SD cards at once.

We've also considered the possibility of having a computer, perhaps an RPi, such that when an SD card is inserted it gets written and `umount`-ed and ejected with no other manual intervention. Would this be easier/more efficient?

Is there a more efficient method we're missing? There is no wifi available, Bluetooth may be an option but I anticipate it being much slower. MS Windows or Linux (pref Ubuntu) options are useful to us. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The device you are looking for is called "[SD card duplicator](https://www.google.com/search?q=SD%20card%20duplicator)". Prices range form $100 to above $1000. Your choice.